# Iterating over the php object does not show me all of the available key/vals

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recently started customising a Wordpress plugin for a client and have hit a problem that I havent been able to explain yet. It's been a few years since I played with php but still I couldnt find an answer anywhere.

The values that I have been looking for are custom fields of a post. They seem to be stored in the `wp_postmeta` table. Somehow I can reference these key/values directly, but I cant see them when I iterate over the object.

I have tried:

```
foreach($myObj as $key=>$value){
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

but the key/values that I needed did not print. So I thought I'd have a quick play with:

```
$vars = get_object_vars ( $Obj );
foreach($vars as $var){
    echo "$var\n";
}
```

...which also failed.

Out of curiosity I also tried iterating over:

```
get_class_methods($myObj)
```

...but that didnt help. I went looking through the code for a clue and found a reference to a property that I needed. When I echo'd out that property I got the result I expected. e.g.

```
echo $myObj->_my_missing_key_val // works!!
```

So why wasnt _my_missing_key_val in my iterated list of available key/vals, and how can I print all the available custom fields list.

How can it be that I can print this missing key/val at all if it isnt a property of $myObj?

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any errors? also is it possible that $value has no string representation and is dying? `var_dump()` might be a better option for debugging purposes

Comment: No errors. It prints up a stack of vars, just not my custom fields. Its like they are there, but they are hidden or something. I will try var_dump tonight.